# Dynamically get link to Desktop on PC for any user

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to get the path to Desktop `C:\Users\Username\Desktop` for any user? I'll like to store it in a variable. Currently, I have mine hardcoded in a function

Comment: There are Windows variables that you can use %SOMETHING%... I don't remember which exists to point out the user home, after you only have to append \Desktop.

Comment: On what operating system? If this is purely for Windows, use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the shell library.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  See the linked Microsoft documentation.